# How to derive equations of motion for scalars?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, calculus

If $s$ is distance covered, $u$ is initial speed and $v$ is final speed, $a$ is a constant acceleration, how to prove that $v^2=u^2+2as$?

We know how to prove it for velocity, displacement using integration, can we use integration to derive these as well?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the chain rule, namely that $\dfrac {dv}{dt} = \dfrac{dv}{ds}\dfrac{ds}{dt}=\dfrac{dv}{ds}v$.

You then have $$a= v\dfrac{dv}{ds}$$
integrate and solve for $v$, you're done

---

EDIT: for the 2/3D case, we repeat the same process as above except we do it for each component; we get $a_x= v_x\dfrac{dv_x}{ds_x},\quad a_y= v_y\dfrac{dv_y}{ds_y}$. From there, we get $v_x^2=u_x^2+2a_xs_x$ and $v_y^2=u_y^2+2a_ys_y$. Add these equations together, and you get $\mathbf{\vec v}^2=\mathbf{\vec u}^2 + 2\mathbf{\vec a}\cdot\mathbf{\vec s}$, which relates the vector quantities.

Comment: Why didn't you just edit your previous answer? +1 Also, since $a$ is constant, $a\int ds = \frac{1}{2} v^2\mid_u^v$ so $v^2=u^2+2as$

Comment: @josephh late night here, didn't think of editing (lol). Thanks:)

Comment: How are we using the fact that $u, v$ are scalers and not vectors?

Comment: Furthermore, integration usually gives signed area? So are we sure that we are using distance and not displacement?

Comment: i did it in 1-D. see my edit @green_blue

Comment: and yes we are using displacement

Answer (score 0):

The equations $v-u=at,\,v+u=2s/t$, which multiply to $v^2-u^2=2as$, can both be proven with integration (though it seems like overkill), viz. $v-u=\int_0^tadt^\prime,\,s=\int_0^t(u+(v-u)t^\prime/t)dt^\prime$.